# Using EC2 metadata credentials in the Laravel filesystem

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I tell the Laravel filesystem layer to use the s3 metadata on an EC2 instance? I don't want to provide hardcoded keys and secrets for my s3 buckets. I'm unclear on what the configuration should look like. When I exclude the key and secret from the filesystem configuration I get the following error

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: key
```

Comment: I have only a vague, passing familiarity with Laravel but based on general knowledge of AWS, it looks to me like if you are using something like [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/blob/master/README.md) that incorporates the official AWS PHP SDK then the instance role credentials would be used automatically if you don't provide static credentials.  The solution *may* be easier than it seems like it would be, but I don't honestly know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix is to leave empty placeholder values in place for key and secret. eg, in config/filesystems.php

```
return [
    'cloud' => 's3',    
    'disks' => [
         's3' => [
             'driver' => 's3',
             'key' => '',
             'secret' => '',
             'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
             'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
         ],
    ],
];
```